# Can anyone help provide an additional example of complex inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A complex inner product is defined as the following, where $C$ is a field of complex numbers, and $F$ is the field of real numbers.

> [image]

I have two examples of complex inner product,

> [image]

I want to know if someone can help give a third example of complex inner product that is not based on $x^Hy$ for $x,y\in C^n$. Thank you!

Comment: Define on $\ell^2(\mathbb C)$ the function $(x = (x_n), y = (y_n)) \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n \overline{y_n}$, this function is an inner product. Or on $L^2((a,b))$, $(f,g) \mapsto \int_a^b f(x) \overline{g(x)}dx$.

Comment: Thank you! But I want an example for vectors in the classic sense, not for a vector space consisting of functions.